# Advice needed to display images in isotope load more function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-isotope

I have the following situation in which I hope for your help. Here is a link to full example: https://jsfiddle.net/7kpfqLr6/25/

Let me explain. I'm trying to set the number of **images** before load more button. The problem is, as you can see, the first isotope item is a **text item**. All other items are images. Now, when I set the number of the images to 6, then it shows 6 isotope items (first text item + 5 images). Yes, it is logical, and I understand that. But I want it to display 6 images after first item. How to do it? Can I count on your help?

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope-items-wrap').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
         transitionDuration: '0.5s',
         masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
         }
  });

  //****************************
  // Isotope Load more button
  //****************************
  var initShow = 6; //number of images loaded on init & onclick load more button
  var counter = initShow; //counter for load more button
  var iso = $container.data('isotope'); // get Isotope instance

  loadMore(initShow); //execute function onload

  function loadMore(toShow) {
    $container.find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");

    var hiddenElems = iso.filteredItems.slice(toShow, iso.filteredItems.length).map(function(item) {
      return item.element;
    });
    $(hiddenElems).addClass('hidden');
    $container.isotope('layout');

    //when no more to load, hide show more button
    if (hiddenElems.length == 0) {
      $("#load-more").hide();
    } 
    else {
      $("#load-more").show();
    };

  }

  //append load more button
  $container.after('<div class="margin-top-30 text-center"><button id="load-more" class="btn btn-primary margin-top-5"> Load More</button></div>');

  //when load more button clicked
  $("#load-more").click(function() {
    if ($('#filters').data('clicked')) {
      //when filter button clicked, set initial value for counter
      counter = initShow;
      j$('#filters').data('clicked', false);
    } else {
      counter = counter;
    };

    counter = counter + initShow;

    loadMore(counter);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the value of:

```
var initShow = 7;
```

then change it to 6 after the initial load afterwards.

```
$("#load-more").click(function() {
    if ($('#filters').data('clicked')) {
      //when filter button clicked, set initial value for counter
      counter = initShow;
      j$('#filters').data('clicked', false);
    } else {
      counter = counter;
    };
    initShow = 6;
    counter = counter + initShow;

    loadMore(counter);
  });
```

The initial load will show `6 images` and additional `6 images` if you `click` load more `button`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not quite what I want to achieve. Let me explain better. Users are given an option to change the number of images that will be displayed before the load more button. For example, if user decides to show 6 images he enters only one number -> 6. Currently, it shows 5 images + text item = 6 items. This is not what I want. I want 6 images + text item.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have a native English speaker, it is a bit difficult for me to explain.